# bad_alloc on vector.push() and vector.reserve()

Tags: c++, vector, bad-alloc

I am trying to build a vector of `GLfloat` of size `772538368`. While doing `push_back()` I am getting `bad_alloc` error.

After checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428663/crash-from-a-push-back-in-a-std-vector), I tried to `reserve()` memory for the vector. However, now I am getting the same error on the attempt of `reserve()` itself.

On my machine, `vector.max_size: 1073741823`, which is bigger than what I need. In other details, I am using VS 2015 on Windows 10. Also please find the relevant code snippets below.

What should I do to resolve this?

Relevant code snippet:

```
int main() {

    vector<GLfloat> targetVector; 
    targetVector.reserve(772538368); //Attempt2 to reserve. Also tried resize()

    vector<vector<vector<GLshort>>> my3DimensionalData;
    //build my3DimensionalData //no problem here.

    //targetVector.reserve(772538368); //Attempt1 to reserve.

    for (GLint rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (GLint colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfCols; colIndex++)
        {
            for (GLint depthIndex = 0; depthIndex < numberOfDepths; depthIndex++)
            {
                //perform gymnastic here on my3DimensionalData and get data.

                /*initially I was getting bad_alloc while pushing back  
                 *elements in the following block.
                 *This led to Attempt1 and Attempt2 as shown above.
                 */
                targetVector.push_back(data1);
                targetVector.push_back(data2);
                ...
                targetVector.push_back(data7);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `sizeof(GLfloat)`? You need `sizeof(GLfloat)` * 736.75MB memory for the processing.

Comment: Is your program compiled as 32-bit? If so, change to 64-bit because otherwise you won't ever be able to create such a big array in 32-bit mode.

Comment: About [`std::vector::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size), "At runtime, the size of the container may be limited to a value smaller than max_size() by the amount of RAM available."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most likely going to need a 64 bit build. You need over 3 GB of *contiguous* memory, and that is almost all of your 4GB memory space.

Comment: While it may be obvious, I'm compelled to mention that running on a 64-bit OS isn't sufficient. You also need to compile for 64-bits (as this answer suggests).